# Java GUI, need to use an actionlistener?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jlist

I have a GUI with 2 JLists. I need only one selection in total across both lists to be selected at a time, for example if the user has selected something in 1 list, selecting something in the other list will cause the one in the 1st list to be deselected. My thought was simply to use an actionlistener on the lists, so when anything in one list is selected, the other list will be deselected, but apparently this doesn't work. I have read up on this subject, and it appears that the general consensus is to use a mouseListener to do this. Is this the only way? I don't really want to add a huge amount of extra code to my program, seeing as I already have actionlistener code set up. I don't care what is selected in each list, I don't even need to know the index, I just need to know when anything is selected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `ListSelectionListener` like this:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // deactivate other list
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I have been doing other things, sorry for the late reply. I am just trying this out now, this code looks good, I am confident it will work, will post again once I have tried it

Comment: Although, looking at that, the parens look a little off, why do you have a method inside of brackets? shouldnt it be:

Comment: `list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()); {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // deactivate other list
    }
}`

Comment: dammit, I cant seem to get the formatting right in this website, but I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html is very unhelpful. This only gives details on how to create a single listener that listens for all changes, as far as I can tell, and I cannot find the link between the list they defined and the actionlistener at all. It seems they just have a single listener listening for any sleection change, and that is not what I need. I need to know when anything at all is selected in a specific list. Unfortunately your code throws about 10 different errors. I have tried to correct it, but I can't. Any advice?

Comment: It's called an anonymous inner class. Basically, you are extending `ListSelectionEvent` with defining a separate class.

Comment: OK, I understand a bit more now. Looking up on those now.

Comment: OK, I understand the concept of Anonymous Inner Classes, but how do I use these to implement a ListSelectionListener? The code you gave to me still throws countless errors (over 100 in the compiler) any way I format it, any way I arrange the brackets. When I comment out the code, the errors are all gone. Can it really be so complicated just to check for a click? All the other elements seem to respond to actionlisteners, why the difference with JLists?

Comment: OK, this is getting extremely frustrating. I asked some IRL programming friends and they said to use a FocusListener, which looks to be the simplest way to do this, but I am already using ActionListeners, and since they require you to use `implements ActionListener`, I can't also use `implements FocusListener`. I am going out of my mind right now, I can't see how this can be so complicated! All I need it to do is detect a click on an element in a list, a focuslistener will do that perfectly, but I cant use it! Arghhhhh!

Comment: What is IRL? You don't need to `implements` anything. That's the purpose of anonymous inner class.

Comment: I'll post a full source code for you below in a few minutes.

Comment: Here is my code, I am doubting my own sanity right now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By8la8SVQxwoMF80eDRRMHIwWkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you considered all the ways to prevent your case where elements in both lists are selected? Like disabling the other list when a selection is made (Component.setEnabled(false))

Second, you could use an ItemListener for your purposes. Be aware that your probably only want to process the event if it has `getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED`

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo for your own understanding:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Demo extends JFrame {
    String[] options = {"1. Something", "2. Something", "3. Something", "4. Something"};
    JList<String> list;

    Demo() {
        setSize(640, 480);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        list = new JList<String>(options); // set options in list
        add(list); // add list to current frame
        pack();

        // bind event listener to list

        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Something happened");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo(); // initialize demo
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this? I ran it and it clearly demonstrates the concept.